# Unix Loop and add comma for JSON

Tags: bash, shell, loops, foreach

I'm working on a csv file to import to JSON code.
I want to add `"` in the middle of the `echo`
and in the loop add `,` to separate no in the end.

This is the variable IMG. (In this example I have 2  URLs, but maybe  this can be more.)

```
img="https://example.com/img/p/8/1/1/811.jpg,https://example.com/img/p/8/0/8/808.jpg"
```

This is my code:

```
img=$(echo   $img |  tr -d '"')
echo "    \"pictures\":["                             >>"$output_filename"
    for imgt in ${img//,/ }
    do
    echo "    {\"source\":$imgt} "                    >>"$output_filename"
    done
    echo ']'                                          >>"$output_filename"
    echo '}'                                          >>"$output_filename"
```

The result

```
  "pictures":[
{"source":"https://quierotodo.com.ar/img/p/8/1/1/811.jpg} 
{"source":https://quierotodo.com.ar/img/p/8/0/8/808.jpg"}
]}
```

Expected result

```
   "pictures":[
{"source":"https://quierotodo.com.ar/img/p/8/1/1/811.jpg"}, 
{"source":"https://quierotodo.com.ar/img/p/8/0/8/808.jpg"}
]}
```

Can you suggest some option to add `,` in the middle of the code not in the last?

Comment: Don't try to create JSON by hand. Install the `jq` utility to parse and create JSON in shell scripts.

Comment: I have the  jq installed  , can i implement in this part of code ? Thx

Comment: Yes, you should be able to do it. I don't know the exact code offhand, I'd have to read the documentation. Give it a try and come back if you have code that you need help with.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I modified your script a bit and:

```
#!/bin/bash
#
img="https://example.com/img/p/8/1/1/811.jpg,https://example.com/img/p/8/0/8/808.jpg"

# Remove the double quotes
img=$(echo $img | tr -d '"')

# Split on the comma, and create an array
IFS=',' read -ra images <<< "$img"

# Start the JSON
echo "\"pictures\":["

# loop through the images, and output the JSON
# keep track of the index of output items
counter=1
for image in "${images[@]}"
do
    echo -n "    {\"source\":\"$image\"}"
    # Add a comma unless it is the last element in the array
    if [ $counter -lt ${#images[@]} ]
    then
        echo ","
    else
        echo ""
    fi
    (( counter = counter + 1 ))
done

# Close the JSON
echo "]}"
```

I transformed `$img` into an array.  Then I output the JSON based on the array.  Unless it is the last item in the array, I add a comma next to the item.

The output is:

```
$ ./so.bash 
"pictures":[
    {"source":"https://example.com/img/p/8/1/1/811.jpg"},
    {"source":"https://example.com/img/p/8/0/8/808.jpg"}
]}
```

You will have to modify it to add an opening `{` somewhere.

Comment: Hi again Nic , thx you solve my problem!  This work like a charm!
I learn about your script , the only i dont undertand  is  the "${images[@]}".
What means this ?
Thx alot

Comment: `${images[@]}` means "all the items in the array".  `$images` is the array of images created with the `read -ra images`, and `[@]` means "all the indexes".  Like when you process arguments, you can use `$@` to refer to all the arguments received.  If it solves your question, I would appreciate it if you could check mark it (left of the answer).  Also, note that while this works, `jq` is the "best" solution for JSON in shell, like it was pointed out before.

Comment: NIC can i do some like this whit for ?

img= "1.jpg,2.jpg,3.jpg,4.jpg,5.jpg,6.jpg,7.jpg,8.jpg" 8 images files

Can i do some like this show only six primary images ? Thx

Comment: Sure, you can list them in the `$img` variable.  Or, if you filenames are a sequence of integers, you can loop (using `for` or `while`) and increment a counter from 1 to 6 to build the filenames.

Comment: Nic i fix this issues whit this pice of code
'for image in "${images[@]:0:6}"' and a if for the coma , its working very well
Thx alot